# Move overlapping labels automaticly

Tags: qgis, labeling, overlapping-features

I want to display and label a point layer with 1000 objects. But many points are on top of each other and the labels overlap. Is there any way that the overlapping labels are automatically moved further out?

I cannot reduce the number of captions any further.

The font size is 5pt.

The placement is in "Cartographic" mode with a distance of 1.

To arrange the labels manually, there are too many points.

[image: map section]

I use QGIS version 3.18.1 for this. What can I do?

Comment: I suggest you reduce the amount of features, omit the labels, or change the scale. At the current scale there's no way this would look good and be easily readable w/o a lot of manual work. What do you points represent?

Comment: I would like to display the locations of customers with their customer numbers. In cities, the customers are so dense that there are overlaps.

Comment: What stops you from changing the scale when you deal with clusters?

Comment: The map should be printed in DIN A3.

Comment: Which doesn't prevent you from changing the scale. It will cover less area, but the points will be visible better. That's the usual tradeoff in cartography: Good readability, a large area covered and a quick prep time. You can't have all three. I'd debate the decision to print the map, since there's no use in doing so.